# undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, split

I am building a simple asset manager app in Rails 4.2.2 and Ruby 2.2.2.  In my `asset` model I'm using a callback with `before_create` to call a function `generate_asset_number` like so

```
def generate_asset_number
        company = "AMS"
       if Asset.count == 0
        self.asset_number = "#{company}-00001"
       else
        last = Asset.last.asset_number
       end
        number = last.split('-')[1].to_i
        number += 1
        self.asset_number = company + '-' + "%05d" % number
      end
    end
```

As you can see I'm setting the company variable as a string, evaluating if the Asset.count is 0 then returning the string "AMS-00001", if the Asset.count is not 0 then I'm assigning last to Asset.last.asset_number to pull the last number in the sequence.

Where I'm getting tripped up is with setting the number variable to return the last incident number and call split on it to extract the second part of the array and convert to integer so I can increment it.

When I run this from the console or try to create a new record in the view, I get the following error:

`undefined method`split' for nil:NilClass`

I'm sure my syntax is off as I'm more of a Ruby Jr.

If anyone can help explain what I need to do to refactor and make this work, I'd appreciate it.  If you need further information or if my question is not clear, please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> undefined method split' for nil:NilClass`

The error is because the life of `last` variable has ended in the `if-else` loop and you are trying to access `last` **outside** the `if-else` loop in this line `number = last.split('-')[1].to_i`. You need to tweak your code like this

```
def generate_asset_number
  company = "AMS"
  if Asset.count == 0
    self.asset_number = "#{company}-00001"
  else
    last = Asset.last.asset_number
    number = last.split('-')[1].to_i
    number += 1
    self.asset_number = company + '-' + "%05d" % number
  end
end
```

Comment: This worked excellent, Sorry, it's very early for me and I was making newb mistakes.  I had refactored something similar to your answer in the interim but it used an extra if statement.  So this is much cleaner!  Thanks so much <3